# Encrypted SSD - Disk usage

Tags: encryption, 16.04

I have a SSD in my laptop, only a small one 128GB.
Its also encrypted. I am running out of space, used something like 99.1% of space.

When I try to check the disk usage I can only see the encrypted folders. How do I find what is using what?

Any suggestions?

[image: Attached Photo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That /home/.ecryptfs/username folder holds the encrypted contents of your (username's) home, you should be able to see the decrypted contents at /home/username or just `~` (if it's being decrypted successfully when you login).

I *think* running `du -sh ~` and `du -sh /home/.ecryptfs/username/` should show similar sizes.

Deleting files in your (mounted) home should delete the corresponding encrypted files in /home/.ecryptfs/username so you'll essentially free twice as much space when deleting files in your home.

Comment: Just to clarify because it is not visible on the screenshot from the original question: ignore the .ecryptfs entry in the Disk Usage Analyser and go further down to see what is under your Home Folder entry. This is the one referenced /home/username in the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the encrypted directory (either by logging in with the user account owning it or with `ecryptfs-mount-private`) and run Disk Usage on the mount point. Then you will see the file names.

Comment: I am logged into the machine with the account that owns it

Comment: Since you seem to have set up ecryptfs to encrypt the entire user home, you and Disk Usage should see the decrypted files in your home directory.